# How to cite a database from R or another source

Tags: citations, journals

I use `data()` from R, i get the following info from the `sunspot` dataset:

> Yearly numbers of sunspots from 1700 to 1988 (rounded to one digit).
>    Source: H. Tong (1996) Non-Linear Time Series. Clarendon Press, Oxford, p. 471.

But in the way I need to reference it, It seems that it is not enough information. The data I need:

```
@misc{anudc:4896
author = {Claire O'Brien},
title = {{Impact of Colonoscopy Bowel Preparation on Intestinal Microbiota},
doi = {10.4225/13/511C71F8612C3},
howpublished= {\url{http://dx.doi.org/10.4225/13/511C71F8612C3}}
```

Im not sure about how to reference properly a data set, in terms of which info is enough, not the style of references.

Comment: Can you please explain why you believe that not to be enough information? (Note that more references are available in `library(boot); help("sunspot")`.)

Comment: Those examples seem like they contain enough information to me. If you’re not sure how to reference a data set, why not read the APA, MLA, or University of Chicago guidelines? They’re easily available on google.

Comment: Please I re-edited, there's no enough info I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
@article{tong1990non,
title={Non-linear time series},
author={Tong, Howell},
journal={A Dynamical System Approach},
year={1990},
publisher={Oxford Univ. Press}
}
```

I used google scholar to find the right citation. Took less than a minute :)